# setInterval on array

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Is it possible to do the following using javascript/jquery?

using setInterval with an array of function names, if the array only has 1 function, it should do the following if the user opens the webpage at 10:00:00

```
function 1 - 10:00:00
function 1 - 10:00:01
function 1 - 10:00:02
function 1 - 10:00:03
function 1 - 10:00:04
```

then if the user clicks another button, a new function name gets added to the array, which ends up doing the following:

```
function 1 - 10:00:05
function 2 - 10:00:06
function 1 - 10:00:07
function 2 - 10:00:08
function 1 - 10:00:09
function 2 - 10:00:10
function 1 - 10:00:11
function 2 - 10:00:12
function 1 - 10:00:13
```

if the user clicks the button a 3rd time, a new function name gets added to the array, which ends up doing the following:

```
function 1 - 10:00:14
function 2 - 10:00:15
function 3 - 10:00:16
function 1 - 10:00:17
function 2 - 10:00:18
function 3 - 10:00:19
function 1 - 10:00:20
function 2 - 10:00:21
function 3 - 10:00:22
```

Is this possible?  If it is possible, could someone please help me with some example script on how to get this to happen?

Comment: Definitely not impossible. Edited tags.

Comment: Point taken!  I've edited my original question

Comment: I note that your question is worded to refer to a list of "function names".  In my answer I assumed that a list of actual function instances would work out just as well, but perhaps there's some detail that's been left out.

Comment: To give more detail, I have an ajax based webpage which gets a list of "widgets" which are basically javascript functions stored in a database. The user can choose which widgets to display on his/her screen. Each widget needs to be as real time as possible, but I didn't want to overload the server if the user has 10 widgets on the screen all querying the database every second, so I thought, the more widgets they have, the more spaced out their requests fro the server should be, i.e. no more than 1 request per user per second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple mechanism:

```
var intervalWork = (function() {
  var workers = [], wi = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!workers.length) return;
    workers[wi](wi);
    wi = (wi + 1) % workers.length;
  }, 60 * 1000);

  return function(w) {
    workers.push(w);
  };
})();
```

Then you have a function called "intervalWork" that allows a function to be added to the queue. One function per timer interval (60 seconds here) will be run.  The functions are passed their index in the queue; that doesn't seem generally interesting but it'd let you print out those messages.

The function would be called like this:

```
intervalWork(function(index) {
  // do interesting stuff
  console.log("Function " + index + " " + new Date());
});
```

Or you could call it and pass the name of an already-defined function:

```
intervalWork(someRandomFunction);
```

You could of course make this fancier and provide for other execution modes, or whatever. You didn't describe the overall point of this code so I don't really know what more you'd want.

*edit* — one more note: many people might (rightly) suggest that instead of a timer driven by the browser's `setInterval()` mechanism, it might be better to use `setTimeout()` and do the work of setting up each subsequent timer yourself. That can be important in cases much like yours, where the amount of work done is sort-of unbounded because you don't control what those "worker" functions do. The basic setup would be the same however.

Comment: Yes, stopping the timer, re-starting it, removing entries from the worker list, even clearing out the whole list to start over; all those things might be added to this mechanism.

Comment: how would I run everything in the array?  Like this?  intervalWork();

Answer (score 1):

```
var functions = [function () {console.log('function 1')}];
var idx = 0;

setInterval(function () {
  functions[idx]();
  idx = (idx + 1) % functions.length;
}, 1000);

// on button click:
functions.push(function () {console.log('function 2')});
```